# Make Maven Spotless plugin format Kotlin source code

Tags: maven, kotlin, spotless

How do I get the Spotless Maven plugin to format all Kotlin source files?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
    <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>spotless-apply</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <kotlin>
                    <ktlint/>
                </kotlin>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>apply</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why your current configuration doesn't work, maybe its because the config is inside the execution block? If you move it up one level and then replace the `apply` with `check` it will work.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
    <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <kotlin>
            <ktlint />
        </kotlin>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Changing the goal to "apply" worked after I moved the configuration as you suggested.